# Scraping para descargar archivo con Selenium y Python

Tags: python, selenium, scraping

espero se encuentren muy bien.
Estoy intentando descargar un archivo desde la siguiente url:

https://www.dane.gov.co/index.php/estadisticas-por-tema/industria/encuesta-mensual-manufacturera-con-enfoque-territorial-emmet

debo descargar el archivo de de la opcion "Anexo total nacional, asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

obtengo el path para esta parte del código, asi:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y hago lo siguiente:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*@id="cnpv"]/div/div/table[1]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[4]/a').click()
```

pero el codigo me genera el siguiente error:

ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element is not clickable at point (1147, 844)
(Session info: chrome=99.0.4844.51)

Stacktrace:
Backtrace:

```
Ordinal0 [0x01039943+2595139]
Ordinal0 [0x00FCC9F1+2148849]
Ordinal0 [0x00EC4528+1066280]
Ordinal0 [0x00EF7621+1275425]
Ordinal0 [0x00EF5657+1267287]
Ordinal0 [0x00EF333B+1258299]
Ordinal0 [0x00EF207D+1253501]
Ordinal0 [0x00EE7AB3+1211059]
Ordinal0 [0x00F0B9EC+1358316]
Ordinal0 [0x00EE7474+1209460]
Ordinal0 [0x00F0BC04+1358852]
Ordinal0 [0x00F1BAF2+1424114]
Ordinal0 [0x00F0B806+1357830]
Ordinal0 [0x00EE6086+1204358]
Ordinal0 [0x00EE6F96+1208214]
GetHandleVerifier [0x011DB232+1658114]
GetHandleVerifier [0x0129312C+2411516]
GetHandleVerifier [0x010CF261+560433]
GetHandleVerifier [0x010CE366+556598]
Ordinal0 [0x00FD286B+2173035]
Ordinal0 [0x00FD75F8+2192888]
Ordinal0 [0x00FD76E5+2193125]
Ordinal0 [0x00FE11FC+2232828]
BaseThreadInitThunk [0x76EFFA29+25]
RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77777A9E+286]
RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77777A6E+238]
```

Me podrian por favor ayudar a validar porque el archivo no se puede descargar y cual instrucción seria valida para hacerlo.  Muchas gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: Al final pudieron solucionar el problema ?

Comment: Verifica en el código de HTML si esa tabla se encuentra dentro de otra iFrame. Deberás entrar primero a la iFrame en donde se encuentra el botón y luego colocar el xpath.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu ruta xpath parece incorrecta, prueba lo siguiente:

```
driver.get('https://www.dane.gov.co/index.php/estadisticas-por-tema/industria/encuesta-mensual-manufacturera-con-enfoque-territorial-emmet')

downloadfile= driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/article/section/div[2]/div/div/table[1]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[4]/a')

downloadfile.click()
```

Comment: Hola @Pepe N O, de antemano muchas gracias por responder.  Con tu codigo me sigue generando el mismo error que puse en la descripción de la pregunta.

Comment: Si, a cierto número de ejecuciones la página previene la navegación automatica, aparentemente.

Comment: Hola @Pepe N O , si  eso parece , en los primeros intentos no permite la descarga, muchas gracias por la ayuda.